# How to upload columns in the subsites when I upload a document?

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a siteCollection with 2 subSites.

When I upload a document, I have a workflow that upload this document in this 2 subSites.

Here is my publishing library url:

```
http://WebURL/sites/Dev/Lists/IntranetPublishingList/AllItems.aspx
```

I have here e.g Department column.

And here is my subSites library url:

```
http://WebURL/sites/Dev/SubSite1/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

http://WebURL/sites/Dev/SubSite2/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

The problem is that I want the same columns of publishing library in my 2 subsites library.
(e.g department).

How to realize this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but questions regarding Nintex is off topic here, and should be asked on their support forums. If you want to, you can strip out the part about nintex and instead ask for a "generic" solution to your problem. That way the question will be on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 'site columns' at the top level in the site collection (looks like sites/Dev in your case) specifying all of the values/options/types that you need.

Then when you create each list in your subsites, you can add the 'site columns' by going to 'Library' -> 'Library Settings' then under the 'Columns' heading, select 'Add from existing site columns.'

That way, all of the columns will be exactly the same and accept exactly the same values, and as an added benefit if you ever change the 'site column' definition, that change will be inherited by every list that references the site column as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand because columns are already created, but I don't see this columns in the site column list? They aren't site columns?

Comment: Correct - you need to create new site columns that contain all of the properties that you want, then make all the lists use those site columns instead of their own copies. Although I hate this site because of the ad it shows a few seconds after you open the page, it has a pretty good run down on site columns: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/learn-sharepoint-site-columns